# Why this error occurs nodejs on windows?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows

Here is my code:

```
var exec = require('child_process').spawn;
var job = exec("tasklist",  ["/v", "/fo", "csv"]);

// var buffer;
job.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    // buffer += data.toString();
    console.log(data.toString());
});
job.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('job stderr: ' + data);
});
job.on('close', function (code, signal) {
    // console.log(buffer);

    // CSV transform 

});
```

and when I run  node test.js, I get the following error:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: write EIO
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)`enter code here`
    at Object.afterWrite (net.js:718:19)
```

Why did this happen?

Comment: What is the task list program you're trying to run

Comment: Your second `job.stderr.on` registers the event `data` again. Your probably want to get the error-event there?

Comment: `tasklist` is windows built-in command.

https://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc730909(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: That the results of the tasklist that 's an error that occurs when that contains multi-byte character was found .

Answer (score 0):

That the results of the tasklist that 's an error that occurs when that contains **multi-byte character** was found .